# Can a user see records when DeletedDatabaseRecord is true?

Tags: acumatica

Can an admin user see all records in a table including the ones marked DeletedDatabaseRecord = 1 or will these records never be seen by a user unless marked as DeletedDatabaseRecord = 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data retrieval is blocked at the Select layer according to documentation.
Displaying a record in the UI requires a Select command to fetch the record. The records with DeletedDatabaseRecord field set to true (1) will not be returned by BQL select and therefore shouldn't be displayed to the user.

Source: [Preservation of Deleted Records](https://help.acumatica.com/Main?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=4a1939a3-26aa-49e3-83c6-5bcc884e66b9)

> When data records are selected from the table, the data access layer
>   generates the SQL query, which returns only data records that are not
>   marked as deleted.